# Debug a Spring Boot application started in custom task in Intellij

Tags: java, spring-boot, gradle, intellij-idea

I use Spring Boot and want to execute Spotless to reformat code before `bootRun` everytime, so I write the following tasks in my build.gradle.kts:

```
task("startServer") {
    setGroup("Sample category")
    dependsOn(":security:spotlessApply", ":database:spotlessApply").finalizedBy(":convo:bootRun")
}
```

When I execute this task in debug mode, Intellij doesn't stop at the breakpoint, but if I execute the built-in `bootRun` task, it works.

How can I let Intellij debug the Spring Boot application started in my `startServer` tasks?

Answer (score 0):

I find a way to achieve this, instead of writing a custom task, I add `dependsOn` directly in `bootRun` task in the application's (here is my convo module) `build.gradle.kts`:

```
tasks.withType<org.springframework.boot.gradle.tasks.run.BootRun>() {
    dependsOn(":database:spotlessApply").dependsOn(":security:spotlessApply")
}
```